# Does getContentLength() download entire file?

Tags: java, image, download

this is my code for **download an image** width percentage [Java] :

```
URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
    OutputStream os;
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    int fileLenth = connection.getContentLength();
    try (InputStream is = url.openStream()) {
        os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;
        int count = 0;
        double sumCount = 0.0;
        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);

            sumCount += count;
            if (fileLenth > 0) {
                System.out.println("Percentace: " + (sumCount / fileLenth * 100.0) + "%");
            }
        }
    }
    os.close();
```

i want to know when i using :

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
int fileLenth = connection.getContentLength();
```

Is the file is downloaded?
If this is true, the file will be downloaded **twice**, and this is not good
can you help me for best performance ?
thanks

Comment: @Titus You should make that an answer.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for the suggestion, I've just did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getContentLength()` method doesn't download the file, it just returns the value of the `content-length` header (if there is one), [more details here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getContentLength())